# React: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm playing around with React and I am getting the functionality I want but it is extremely slow due to an infinite loop somewhere.  I believe it's in the component lifecycle methods but I'm not sure how to reformat the below code to have the same functionality but without the infinite loop.  Any advice on best practices would be appreciated.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      num: 13,
      num2: 10,
      total: 0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.addNums();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.addNums();
  }

  addNums(){
    var added = parseInt(this.state.num) + parseInt(this.state.num2);
    this.setState({total: parseInt(added)});
  }

  change(num) {
    this.setState({num: num});
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  change2(num2) {
    this.setState({num2: num2});
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <TopBar />
        <Combinatoric test={this.state.num} changeNumber={this.change.bind(this)}/>
        <Combinatoric test={this.state.num2} changeNumber={this.change2.bind(this)}/>
        <h2>Total: {this.state.total}</h2>
        <h1>hello world</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` calls `addNums` that calls `this.setState` that causes a component to update. Don't store `total` in the state - you can always calculate it right in the `render`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite loop happends because you call `this.addNums()` in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function. `addNums` sets the state which causes a componentUpdate and hence `ComponentDidUpdate` is called again and hence the loop continues.

You can remove this function and since `num` and `num2` are there in the state and `total` can then just be caluculated in the render based on `num` and `num2`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      num: 13,
      num2: 10,
      total: 0
    }
  }


  change(num) {
    this.setState({num: num});
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  change2(num2) {
    this.setState({num2: num2});
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render(){
    var total = parseInt(this.state.num) + parseInt(this.state.num2);
    return (
      <div>
        <TopBar />
        <Combinatoric test={this.state.num} changeNumber={this.change.bind(this)}/>
        <Combinatoric test={this.state.num2} changeNumber={this.change2.bind(this)}/>
        <h2>Total: {total}</h2>
        <h1>hello world</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @MayankShukla Did'nt see that the function was also called in the componetDidMount. Removed it

Comment: It also makes sense to move `parseInt` to the event handlers.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was because of `deep-equal` package used for `react-helmet` component. I fixed it by increasing version from `5.2.0` to `6.0.0-beta`.