# ReactJS change parent style causes RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error when I try to change a parent style based upon some logic in the child component.

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

I've tried putting the call to change the parent in componentWillUpdate and componentShouldUpdate as well as other life cycle events and it just does not seem to want to work.

here is a jsbin to see what is going on. At the end of the slides the background should turn white, which it does, but it also throws the error and causes the app to stop working.

https://jsbin.com/mahocuq/edit?html,js,console,output

```
    componentWillUpdate() {
    if(this.props.slideNum === 2){
        this.changeStyle("#fff")
    }
    console.log(this.props.slideNum);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314933/react-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition says that on update, if you're on slide two, trigger an update to the parent.

When you update the parent, the props get passed down to the child and trigger an update. You're creating an infinite loop.

You would probably want to pass down the background color so you can verify it is what you expect it to be and you don't need any further updates. Fairly untested but something like this should work:

```
<Slides
    currentBackgroundColor={this.state.backgroundColor}
    ChangeParentStyle={this.ChangeParentStyle.bind(this)}
    slideNum={this.state.slideNum}
/>

...
class Slides extends React.Component {
    componentWillUpdate() {
        if(this.props.slideNum === 2 && this.props.currentBackgroundColor !== `#fff`){
            this.props.ChangeParentStyle(`#fff`);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That seems to work. I created a new jsbin: https://jsbin.com/goruge/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @bradrice great. if it works for you can you accept the answer?